# Github Pull Request Builder - Cannot trigger build and cannot set build status on github commit

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using [GitHub pull request builder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin) to setup a build per pull request.

However, this build is not triggered for any new pull request or new commit on a pull request.  There are few  exception on the Jenkins log.  I have no clue what's wrong according to those logs.

Thanks in advance.

```
Sep 22, 2014 12:10:52 AM SEVERE org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbTrigger getBuilds
The ghprb trigger for keeper-pull-request wasn't properly started - helper is null
Sep 22, 2014 12:10:52 AM WARNING hudson.model.listeners.RunListener report
RunListener failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbBuildListener.onStarted(GhprbBuildListener.java:19)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbBuildListener.onStarted(GhprbBuildListener.java:12)
    at hudson.model.listeners.RunListener.fireStarted(RunListener.java:213)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1702)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:232)

Sep 22, 2014 12:10:54 AM INFO jenkins.plugin.assembla.AssemblaProjectProperty$DescriptorImpl getSites
Called getSites size=0
Sep 22, 2014 12:11:00 AM WARNING hudson.triggers.Trigger checkTriggers
org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbTrigger.run() failed for hudson.model.FreeStyleProject@17c57009[keeper-pull-request]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbTrigger.run(GhprbTrigger.java:140)
    at hudson.triggers.Trigger.checkTriggers(Trigger.java:266)
    at hudson.triggers.Trigger$Cron.doRun(Trigger.java:214)
    at hudson.triggers.SafeTimerTask.run(SafeTimerTask.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Finally, the problem is I haven't set `Github project` field in job configuration.

After configed that field, everything works well.

Comment: It's good to see that you resolved your issue. Please accept your answer so that 1) Others can know that your query is resolved. 2) Others will know what the resolution was.

Comment: @Technext Thank you. However, it needs 2 days in SO to accept my own answer.

Comment: Where do you see an option to set project "Github project"? I can not find it on the Jenkins Manage configuration page

Comment: @DoronShai It's under the configuration page of each Jenkins job, on the top section of that page. You can quick locate it by finding 'Github' in this page.